# Converting multiple records into single record T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parsing, pivot

Database issue (we are using T-SQL)

I am currently working on a relation between employees and projects.

We are trying to restructure the database to work something like this.

The old database contained information like this

```
Employee ID  Project ID
1            1
1            2
1            3
2            1
2            2
```

We need to convert it into single records for each employee like so

```
Project ID  Employee ID 1 Employee ID 2
1           1              2
2           1              2
3           1              null
```

Here is the sql code that I have tried but I have been running into issues, now there are more than three for each employee this is just an example.  Trust me if there were only three or two I would just use a max or min and be done with it.

```
Select [Project ID], min([Employee ID])
From dbo.[Employee Project ID]
where [Employee ID] > select ( Min([Employee ID]) form dbo.[Employee Project ID])
Group by [Project ID]
```

First issue this only gives me the second largest, and
if there is not larger element ie if there is only one project the employee has been on it will still return 1 for Employee ID 1 and 1 for Employee ID 2.  I have tried case statements and they have just blown up on me.  Is there an easier way to do this?

I can not simply return all employees on this, I have to put each employee into its own field.  The front end cannot read it if it returns multiple employees for a single field into the project.  I am not writing the front end we are bringing in a new company and they can't change their code.

What I need is each employee in his own field, I'm sorry for the initial mixup, we have hundreds of employees in this database and not all are on each project.  So we need the lowest employee id in the first slot, and the second lowest in the second slot up to 14.  Its going into a funny table that will look like this.  I have no control over how this is shaped I just need to get our initial data into this form.

```
Project ID     Attribute       Information
1              Employee ID 1   1
1              Employee ID 2   2
2              Employee ID 1   1
2              Employee ID 2   2
3              Employee ID 1   1
3              Employee ID 2   null
```

Basically I was going to insert employee ID 1 into the table and insert the employee ID 1 into the field for the attribute.  Honestly if you know of a way to get to the bottom table that would be even better.  I was just trying to save you guys time.

Comment: Don't. Just don't. That is a bad way to store your data. The old way is the **right** way to store this information.

Comment: We are migrating a to a new front end, this is not how the data will be stored.  Basically there will be a new record and each will be stored differently its a little difficult to explain but I don't know a way to give each of these a tag for the attribute name.

Comment: "Front End" means display and UI logic. "Back End" means storage and business rule logic. If you're moving to a new front end, that shouldn't change your storage. Your new front end may **display** data in the new way, but that's different from how it's stored, and somewhere in between you will want code that can pivot your data. The storage side very much needs to remain in the old schema. The new schema is just plain _wrong_. SQL database tables **must** have a _fixed number of columns_, and numbered columns are almost always a very serious design flaw.

Comment: +15 points for @JoelCoehoorn

Comment: Can you just bring it back and format it within your application code?

Comment: I don't write the code, we are bringing in a second company.  Also I just realized I made a mistake.  I'm correcting it now. I apologize for the initial waste of time, thank you everyone for your input.

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with @JoelCoehoorn's comment to leave your table in the current structure.  If you then need to display it in the other version for your application and/or users, then you can use a `PIVOT` similar to this:

```
select EmployeeId,
  [1] ProjectId1, 
  [2] ProjectId2, 
  [3] ProjectId3
from
(
  select EmployeeID, projectid,
    row_number() over(partition by employeeid order by projectid) rn
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  max(projectid)
  for rn in ([1], [2], [3])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9b1bf/2)

Result from this query is:

```
| EMPLOYEEID | PROJECTID1 | PROJECTID2 | PROJECTID3 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|          1 |          1 |          2 |          3 |
|          2 |          1 |          2 |     (null) |
```

Doing it this way, will leave your table in a normalized fashion.  If you have 100 projects, you will not want to have 100 different columns added to your table.  You can easily manipulate the data to get it into the format that you need using either SQL (like above) or in your application's code.

Edit, based on your change, you should still be able to use a `PIVOT` on the existing table structure:

```
select projectid,
  [1] EmployeeID1, 
  [2] EmployeeID2
from
(
  select EmployeeID, projectid,
    dense_rank() over(partition by projectid order by employeeid) dr
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  sum(dr)
  for EmployeeId in ([1], [2])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9b1bf/19)

Result:

```
| PROJECTID | EMPLOYEEID1 | EMPLOYEEID2 |
-----------------------------------------
|         1 |           1 |           2 |
|         2 |           1 |           2 |
|         3 |           1 |      (null) |
```

Comment: @osfp2328 see my edit, with a `PIVOT` version that will still work with employees as the columns

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
declare @t table (EmployeeID int, ProjectId int)
insert @t
select 1, 1
union select 1, 2
union select 1, 3
union select 2, 1
union select 2, 2

select distinct EmployeeID
, 
(
    select ProjectId
    from @t b
    where a.EmployeeId = b.EmployeeId
    for xml path(''), root('Projects')
) ProjectsXML
from @t a
```

Output

```
EmployeeID  ProjectsXML
1           <Projects><ProjectId>1</ProjectId><ProjectId>2</ProjectId><ProjectId>3</ProjectId></Projects>
2           <Projects><ProjectId>1</ProjectId><ProjectId>2</ProjectId></Projects>
```

However it's better to have your UI code take care of this rather than complicate things at the SQL level.